# osx sierra No module named pip

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pip

I recently upgrade to sierra (10.13) and pip is not working anymore, anytime I try to install a package I get 'No module named pip'

```
 pip install setuptools

 Traceback (most recent call last):


File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==9.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 542, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2569, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2229, in load
    return self.resolve()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2235, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
ImportError: No module named pip
```

but if I type 'which pip':

```
 /usr/local/bin/pip
```

I already tried 'brew reinstall python'

I already tried to download get-pip.py and reinstall

I already tried 'python easy_install pip'

I'm sure my environment path is correct 'echo $PATH':

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin/....
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently some links where corrupted so I did

```
 brew unlink python && brew link python
```

and when asked I removed wheel, pip from /usr/local/bin

Hope it helps.